# Сделать несколько админов в telegram bot

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста как сделать несколько админов в telegram bot

```
$bot->command("start", function ($message) use ($bot) {
    $cid = $message->getChat()->getId();
    if($cid == '308194279') // Как правильно добавит сюда несколько админов / 
    //есть переменная $id она выводит 308194279,408194279,408194279 (Но оно так не работает)
    {       
        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), "Все ок");
    }
    else 
    {
        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), "Тебе сюда нельзя.".$cid."");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) возвращает `Boolean` значение если элемент найден.

```
<?php

const AdministrationIdentifiers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

$myId = 1;

if (in_array($myId, AdministrationIdentifiers)) {
    echo "Access granted";
} else {
    echo "Access denied";
}
```

Comment: `const AdministrationIdentifiers = [308194279,408194279,408194279];` Как мне тогда сюда вставать данную переменную? `$id`

Comment: В массив вы помещаете разрешенные идентификаторы, а в самой функции `in_array();` подставляете нужный `ID`, и массив идентификаторов. `in_array(<id>, <массив>);`

Comment: `$id` берётся с базы данных

Answer (score 0):

```php
$bot->command("start", function ($message) use ($bot) {
    $cid = $message->getChat()->getId();

    if(in_array($cid, ['308194279', '408194279', '408194279'])) {       
        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), "Все ок");
    }
    else {
        $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), "Тебе сюда нельзя.".$cid."");
    }
});
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]